# css3 transition instead of .animate()

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

is there a way of instead of using .animate() in jQuery using a css3 transition?

so instead of this code

```
jQuery('#pageHolder').stop().animate({
            left: 950

}, 400, function() {
            calcNav(pageSize);
            calcPage(pageSize);
});
```

can and how would i do this with css transition?

Comment: use jquery transit plugin

Comment: yes, just not your `calc` functions :) Have you used Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```css
#pageHolder{
    -webkit-transition:left 0.4s;
    -moz-transition:left 0.4s;
    -o-transition:left 0.4s;
    transition:left 0.4s;
}
```

Attach handlers to the transition end event

```
jQuery('#pageHolder').on('webkitTransitionEnd transitionend msTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd', 
    function(){
        calcNav(pageSize);
        calcPage(pageSize);
    }
);
```

Change the css property to trigger the event

```
jQuery('#pageHolder').css({left: 950});
```